# rbenv: dynamically extend $PATH for gem binaries

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, rbenv

I got `rbenv` installed, and it works fine:

```
$ rbenv local
3.2.0
$ ruby --version
ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 revision a528908271) [x86_64-linux]
```

I installed the gem `rufo` to format my code, which worked fine:

```
$ gem install rufo
```

It seems that `rbenv` is aware of the binary location of `rufo`:

```
$ rbenv which rufo
/home/patrick/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/bin/rufo
```

However, it cannot be found in my `$PATH`:

```
$ which rufo
which: no rufo in (…)
```

I can run it as follows to format my file `hello.rb`:

```
$ `rbenv which rufo` hello.rb
$ echo $?
0
```

However, I'd like to call it directly as follows:

```
$ rufo hello.rb
```

What do I need to configure?

Comment: Have you tried `rbenv rehash`? What is the output of `rbenv local` and `rbenv global`?

Comment: That absolutely solved my problem! To be precise: it already worked after the last reboot, which of course involves a reload of the profile. However, I just tried it with another gem: puppet. After `gem install puppet`, the binary was not located in `$PATH`. After `rbenv rehash`, it was there. I read about `rbenv rehash` in the new Pickaxe book (Programming Ruby 3.2). They mentioned to run `rbenv rehash`, but didn't give precise reasons for doing so. Now I get it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `rbenv rehash` to update the shims:

```
$ which rufo 
which: no rufo in (…)

$ rbenv rehash
$ which rufo
/home/patrick/.rbenv/shims/rufo
```